# Double \\ appears while reading from internet

Tags: java, encoding, character

I'm reading some information from an external server where I have no access and I don't know the encoding and I've having some problems with characters like `í`. What I do is a POST request using the code below and afterwards, I parse it.

```
String response = "";
URL url = new URL(pURL);
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
if (sid!=null) uc.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sid);
uc.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
osw.write(request);
osw.flush();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String content;
while ((content = br.readLine())!=null){
  response += content;
}
br.close();
osw.close();
```

At this moment, if I print the string it shows a `\\`, I mean, for `í` instead of appearing `\u00ed` appears `\\\u00ed` and if I convert the response string to a char array, I can see that instead of converting it correctly, it's divided into 6 chars `\\\\, u, 0, 0, e, d`.

I've tried to change encoding where the InputStreamReader is, to replace characters and some regex and none did work. Did anyone have this problem and can help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `"UTF8"` and not `"UTF-8"`?

Comment: Just to let you know: *your omitting line feeds*...

Comment: Are you sure the request is returning data in UTF-8.. you should really inspect the Content-Type response header for the encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the response is formatted that way, but you could convert strings with `\u00ed` into `í` using [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) as follows:

```
String input = "\\u00ed";
String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(input);
System.out.println(unescaped);
```

**Output:**

```
í
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response.replaceAll("\\","\");
```

Comment: That won't even compile I'm afraid.